# Cordova: Share files with other apps

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems

I have a Cordova-based app for which I want to implement an import- / export functionality. The app runs on an Android system.

The exported file should be easily accessible from within other apps so that you can for instance use Gmail to send the exported files somewhere else. Likewise, any compatible file that was downloaded via Gmail (or other apps), should be available for imports.

So basically, I would like to [save files that can be used with other apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), namely by using the Android's [`DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) or [`DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) folder which I guess are equivalent to these guys:

[image]

However, the [documentation of the Cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) does not provide insight in this regard.

The only folders that are mentioned there (e.g. dataDirectory and tempDirectory) are useless for sharing data with other apps.

Do you have any ideas?